# Extracting the characters between two - in the current string in an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column in my data containing the following type of data
WRO2->DHLPAKET-ASCHHEIM-DI

Each group of words have its own significance.
I am looking for a way to extract the characters between the second and the third minus. (in this case, its "ASCHHEIM". it might change as per the scenario, so extracting it based on its position would be futile)
I want to extract whatever is in between those - and appear in a column of its own.

Comment: Use Text-To-Columns then choose the column you want

Comment: For a VBA solution see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996833/excel-vba-code-mid-function/31997073#31997073)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, if the suggested method *Text-To-Columns* is not an option somehow, you could use:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),2*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

This part `2*..` stands for `(N-1)*..`, in this case the third 'word'

More information [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string)