# VBA How to use mid function in option explicit

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code , it loops through the destinated folder and every single file in the folder.

i have 2 questions

1) how can i modify this code and add it into my main code so that it would work without having compile error for not declaring the variables

```
For Each cell In Range("B1", Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp))
   With cell
       CodeExists = InStr(1, .Value, "testflow")
       'Check that "Code:" exists
       If CodeExists > 0 Then
           .Value = Mid(.Value, CodeExists + 18, 3)
       End If
   End With
Next
```

2) if question 1 can't be done,

```
wks.Cells(BlankRow, 6).Replace What:="hometmastresh", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

```
wks.Cells(BlankRow, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(wks.Cells(BlankRow, 6), "_"))
```

i would like to know how i can modify these 2 codes so that i can split my original string: `"hometmastresh_enciivedexterXXtresh_tepootsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtepootFile"` that is currently in row E with "X" being unknown numbers and the fact that it will be different in every file.
i would like to split the original string into "XX" into Row F and "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" into Row G respectively

Comment: Are you asking how to declare variables (use the `Dim` keyword) to satisfy `Option Explicit`, or you're asking how to split a string at a specific character index? Is `.Value` the `"20191204..."` string or the `"hometmastresh_..."` string? Please [edit] your post to clarify

Comment: hi @MathieuGuindon sorry if i was not clear, i am asking how to split a string at a specific character index yes, but i added in the first code that uses mid function because i prefer to use it instead of split function so if anyone could advice me on how to satisfy option explicit for the first code and get it to work, it would be great , because i have to use paragraphs of split and replace to achieve the result i want. If you have a way for the split function, please feel free to share! any small contribution might end up helping me!

Comment: `without writing paragraphs of coding which slows down the program...` Your approach is inefficient. Use `.Find` and `.FindNext` to search for "hometmastresh_enciivedexter" and then do the relevant action on that cell. [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started.

Comment: Hi thanks for the link! i tried using this code  `'Dim strSearch As String
    'Dim aCell As Range
     
    'strSearch =  "hometmastresh_enciivedexter"
     
    'Set aCell = wks.Cells(BlankRow, 7).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    'LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    'MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
     
    'If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
     '   aCell.Formula = Replace(aCell.Formula, strSearch, "")
    'End If ` with this code, i am still getting "01tresh_tepoots20191204756890tepootFile" but i only need  "20191204756890"

Comment: @SiddharthRout could you advice me on what is the next step to remove "01tresh_teapoots" and "tepootFile" and only get the date in between them with a more efficient code and how can i add a space in between the date "20191204756890" to become "20191204 756890", all in the same row. its similar to this [VBA code Mid Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996833/excel-vba-code-mid-function/31997073#31997073) 2nd question but i can't seem to implement it into my main code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am still getting "01tresh_tepoots20191204756890tepootFile"

So after you have got the text using `.Find`, you can use `Split`. For example

```
Dim s As String

s = Split("01tresh_tepoots20191204756890tepootFile", "tepoot")(1)
s = Mid(s, 2, 8) & " " & Right(s, 6)
Debug.Print s
```

**Edit**

Your code

```
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    aCell.Formula = Replace(aCell.Formula, , "")
    s = Split(aCell.Value, "tepoots")(1)
End If
```

should be as shown below. This will put "20191204 756890" or whatever the number is in the cell.

```
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    s = Split(aCell.Value, "tepoots")(1)
    s = Mid(s, 2, 8) & " " & Right(s, 6)
    aCell.Value = s
End If
```

Comment: Thanks it works!, but only if i specify the full string.May i know how can i use split without specifying the name/string? because i have a loop which goes through a folder and gets these strings from many files so i can't specify the exact string out, also the format of the string will always be the same , the only variable that will change is the numbers "01" and "20191204756890"

Comment: Will this `"01tresh_tepoots20191204756890tepootFile"` be like `"01tresh_tepootsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtepootFile"`?

Comment: it will be like `"hometmastresh_enciivedexterXXtresh_tepootsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXepootFile"` with 2 parts unknown , sometimes it might appear as `"hometmastresh_enciivedexterXXtresh_tepootsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtepootFile.dump"`

Comment: Than simply use `s = Split(aCell.Value, "tepoot")(1)` Where `aCell` you will get from `.Find`

Comment: Can you update the question with new code that you are using? It is difficult read the code in the comment

Comment: Nope there is no confusion. I understand your question correctly. Simply update your question with the new code that you are using.

Comment: Hi siddharth, it works perfectly! thank you so much! can i please ask one last question? how do i add a space into `"20191204756890"` to become `"20191204 756890"`? because i have used your code and modified the values `If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    s = Split(aCell.Value, "tepoots")(1)
    s = Mid(s, 1, 14) & " " & Right(s, 0)
    aCell.Value = s
End If`  however it does not add a space into it because when 20191204756890 is keyed into excel, it will be converted to E.G 2.0e12 and that happened to me, meaning the space was not added. i'm not sure why it wasn't added in...

Comment: `& Right(s, 0)` Why do you have a `0` there? I think you may want to read up how RIGHT/LEFT/MID works :)

Comment: i read up about how they work and seems like just using `s = Mid(s, 1, 14)  &  " " ` works! but the space is still not appearing... i tried using numberformat `wks.Cells(BlankRow, 7).NumberFormat = "0"`and it is able to convert it into `20190302041640` from `2.01903E+13` but
  is there any other way i can straight convert `20190302041640` to this date format E.g 2019 March 02 13:30pm? because my main purpose is to change this string into a date format .once again thank you so much for helping!

Comment: The reason why I asked is becuase you were to use `Right(s, 6)` and not `Right(s, 0)` ;)

Comment: Oh i see , i tried using `s = Mid(s , 1 ,8 ) & " " & Right(s, 6)`and i got `20190302 otFile`, is my understanding of Mid and Right Function wrong? i'm confused now shouldn't it get the rest of the numbers after the space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203636/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-lalalisa).

Comment: can you join me in the chat above?

Answer (score 1):

Use Left/Right to get the ends of the string and concatenate them with a space

```
Dim v As String
'...
'...
If CodeExists > 0 Then
    v = Mid(.Value, CodeExists + 18, 3)
    .Value = Left(v, 8) & " " & Right(v, 6)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but i have no idea how to declare these variables so that option explicit will be satisfied in my code...  the `.Value` part keeps getting `complie error:Method or data member not found`

Comment: Well it's inside your `With cell...End With` block , so the `.Value` belongs to `cell`